# User getting redirected to home page on Single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on

We are implementing SSO in our Org. This works fine. However, we have set an email alert which notifies user when a record of a certain object is created. In this email alert, we provide the user with the link of the newly created record. When user clicks on this link, user is redirected to the Home page and not the record detail page. Any idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you share an example of your link, exactly as displayed in the email?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `startURL` parameter:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/{your-18-char-org-id}/{your-auth-provider}
?startURL=%2F{record-id}
```

Comment: Thanks. One clarification needed - if i have 2 email alerts, one which gives the link of Account record and 2nd which gives you link of Contact record, how will this work? will it take the user to correct record?

Comment: I think you can customize the Email Template used in your Email Alert. Make sure it contains the URL above and paste in the appropriate `{!Account.Id}` or `{!Account.Id}`