# single sign on org and approval emails

Tags: apex, email-template, opportunity, approval-process, single-sign-on

The more and more I deal with SSO I am finding it requiring special care for existing OOB functionality. When we send out an approval email we send the link of the oppty record to the user and ask them to click on the link to view the deal info.

In most of the cases if the user is already authenticated into salesforce through the SSO page then the browser gets redirected to the right record when the user clicks the link on the email, but when the user is not logged into salesforce that's when I need to start worrying about redirect URL.

When I  use https://instance.salesforce.com/{!oppty_id} it redirects the users to test.salesforce.com(in my case I am testing in a sandbox so test.salesforce.com) .Since we have a SSO enabled Org the users do not have standalone user name and password, what is the right URL to use in the email template so that users will be redirected to the SSO page and not test.salesforce.com and then redirected to the record Id once authenticated.

Due to my minimal knowledge with Single sign on I am unable to form the URL that is synonymous to https://test.salesforce.com/006someID

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a similar answer to your question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/user-getting-redirected-to-home-page-on-single-sign-on